# Error in `mutate()`: ! Problem while computing `img = list.files(...)`

Tags: r

I've encountered an issue I can't seem to solve and wanted your help given I'm not sure it's a bug in `mutate` or in the way I'm using it. I was building Data frame with image links from Flags Folder (ordered by country name). Getting below error when I'm trying to run the code:

```
citizenship_counts <- members %>% filter(hired==FALSE) %>%
  mutate(citizenship = str_replace(citizenship,"W Germany","Germany")) %>%
  group_by(citizenship) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
  top_n(10,n) %>% 
  arrange(citizenship) %>% 
  mutate(img = list.files(here::here('9-22-2020 Conquering The Himilayas',
                                     'Flags'), full.names = TRUE)) %>%
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% mutate(rank = 1:10)

citizenship_counts
```

[image: Error message]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error states that the `list.files(here::here('9-22-2020 Conquering The Himilayas','Flags'), full.names = TRUE))` return value is empty.
Check where `here::here()` thinks it is (and make sure to check in that exact environment / setup) as it can get bit confusing, depending on what exactly are you doing and if you are working with RStudio project or not.

`here::here()` will remember the working directory where `here` was first loaded during the current session, this might differ from the location where the file is saved or where the `getwd()` currently points.